# Generated Ide Helper Files Not Working Inside Controller

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete

I installed the barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper package

This package works well in routes/web.php file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRgKf.png)

Inside Laravel controller, generated ide helper files not working properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEhN3.png)

This package generates helper files that enable your IDE to provide accurate autocompletion.

Comment: Instead of pasting a screenshot of your code, please edit the question and add the code itself